# What is the most efficient query to get all friends' events in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying different variations of getting all friends events on Facebook. What is the most efficient query for doing so in terms of fastest respond time from Facebook. I need to get all the events my or one of my app user's friends are attending or maybe attending.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to get all the events my or one of my app user's friends are attending or maybe attending.

Query the FQL event_member table (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event_member/) using the `uid=me()` (me() refers to the current user for whom the access token belongs to) and check the rsvp_status to be either 'attending' or 'unsure'.

Answer (score 0):

here is the fql for grabbing all friends events, You need the friends_events permission in order to get the events

> SELECT eid,name,pic,start_time,end_time,location,venue.id,privacy,all_members_count,creator,description,attending_count,can_invite_friends FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 =me()) AND start_time >= now() OR uid ='".$user_arr['fbuid']."') and privacy='OPEN' and venue.id<>'' AND start_time >=now() ORDER BY start_time ASC limit 5000